# Given two coordinates, how can you find the angle from the vertical (like a clock face)

Tags: 2d, geometry, trigonometry, angle

I am making a simple birds-eye 2D game where the character can face any direction, the direction the character is facing will be given in radians.

Given two sets of coordinates (point a and b) how do I find the angle between the line directly vertical from a and the line produced from a to b? This angle will be from 0 to 360 (although 360 will be treated as 0).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9TAU.png

In this diagram point a is the centre and point b is the one on the edge. The line extending from a is the 0 position and the line which you will work out the angle from. The point b could be anywhere on the circle and I need to find the radians of the angle to the right of the 0 line.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I studied it back in school, but if point B is on the unit circle, it should be a pretty trivial math problem.

A - If it's in radians, it won't be 0-360!

B - If Y >= 0, angle = arccos(x); else angle = TWOPI - arccos(x)

The usual formulation is that angle=0 is along +X, rather than +Y.  You'll have to tinker a bit to get what you want.  But that should be plenty to nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: Haha yeah, that was silly! I just woke up!
Ah yes, this looks good thanks. I was trying to do it via a CAST diagram, but that meant I had to do a different calculation depending on which quadrant it was in, I felt that there must be a better way. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `atan` function that many programming languages have. From vertical, the angle to point B will be:

```
pi/2 - atan(x, y)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of point B with respect to A. Note that this might be negative, so you'll need to do some modular arithmetic to get it positive (if you care about that.)

Also, this isn't really an appropriate question for StackOverflow, since it's a math question and not a programming one.

Comment: Thanks, ah is it not? I apologise.

Comment: By the way what do you mean by atan(x, y)?

Comment: Arctangent, which every standard math library has.

Comment: Yeah i knew it was arctangent but (x, y) ? What is that comma?

Comment: It would be the function. `x` is the x-coordinate of point B with respect to point A, which would be `B.x-A.x`, and `y` is the y-coordinate of point B with respect to A, which is `B.y-A.y`.